# Does the letter г ever have a soft "J" sound?

Tags: произношение

When they say it sounds like the "G" in English, do they mean the hard G sound like Gary, the soft G like Genuine, or both?

Comment: It can also sound like **в**, like in **нового**

Comment: Just to remind that in final position it's unvoiced (it's a rule, like in German). Флаг (pron. _флак_), флага ("г" as in Gary).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is hard, like in Gary. Hear for example the pronounce of га ([https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/га#Произношение](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).  It is the voiced counterpart of к.

In Russian there is no sound similar to G in Geniune. Such G is transliterated as ДЖ.

Sometimes, г is pronounced as the voiced counterpart of х. This is most common in Ukraine, and among people from Ukraine.  You should not pronounce г like this, but you should recognize such г.

In word endings -ого, -его, and in the pronoun `его`, г is pronounced like в. (But not in the words `ого` and `ого-го`.)

Comment: **Г** pronounced as the voiced counterpart of **Х** is used in Standard Russian too, in some words, that's the norm, everybody is supposed to pronounce those words with such a fricative **Г**. First of all, it's _Бог_. In this word, when  **Г** is final, it's devoiced into **Х**, but when inside the word (_Богу_, _с Богом, боги_) it's exactly like the voiced counterpart of **Х**. Some other words in which **Г** is pronounced the same way: _благо; ага; ого; ого-го._

Comment: Also note, that the Ukrainian **Г** is _not_ "the voiced counterpart of Х" which is [ɣ] in IPA. In fact, the Ukrainian **Г** is a _pharyngeal_ voiced fricative, IPA for it is [ɦ]. In Southern Russia and in Belarus they do pronounce **Г** as [ɣ], but not in Ukraine.

Comment: While for Бог and ага there are two pronuncations, благо is pronounced with hard Г: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE#Pronunciation .

Comment: I did not write anything about Ukrainian language. I wrote about Ukrainian dialect of Russian.  But if you want to talk about Ukrainian, Г in Ukrainian is pronounced as both [ɣ] and [ɦ] according to duolingo.com (https://www.duolingo.com/comment/10344499/A-Russian-learner-s-guide-to-the-Ukrainian-course)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, without context it's impossible to figure out what *they*, whoever they are, mean.

The English so-called hard **G** (or in phonologic terms *voiced velar plosive*) is in principle equivalent to Russian **Г**. However, its hardness in English isn't absolute since in certain positions it softens, retaining nevertheless its *velar plosive* character as in the words ***beGin***, ***nagGing***, ***rugGed***.
Similarly, Russian **Г** can get soft like in the words *дру**Г**ие, но**Г**и, забе**Г**е*

The English so-called soft **G** can be transliterated into Russian as **ДЖЬ**, but Russian doesn't have such a sound, it's uncharacteristic of its phonetic system.
Instead, Russian has a sound denoted by the letter **Ж** used, in particular, at places where **Г** must become soft and so transform into **Ж**.

> вра**Г** - вра**Ж**еский
>   доро**Г**ой - доро**Ж**е
>   сла**Г**ать - сло**Ж**ение
>   запря**Г**ать - запря**Ж**ён
>   мо**Г**у - мо**Ж**ем

That said, the phoneme **Ж** itself is always hard in Russian.

Comment: I thought that only **ж ц ш** were always hard

Comment: @ваян купи-ка isn't **гид** soft? IIRC **и** always makes the preceding consonant soft.

Comment: @Trey yes, you're correct, that was my mistake